# draw isoline from points

Tags: mapserver, openlayers-2, oracle-spatial

Is any spatial utility or methods are available for creating contour or isopleths on `Oracle spatial`? I want to create contours from point geometry and show it on a map (using `mapserver`) of the site. Please share me any idea/information related to this.

Comment: The name for the process you're looking for is interpolation. I don't know anything about Oracle Spatial, but that might help you find something in the documentation. Sometimes you can interpolate directly to contours, sometimes you have to go to a surface or TIN first and then generate contours from that.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:
https://github.com/ThomasG77/turf-ol3

Use ol3 for map(from mapserver or any xyz map), and turf for some drawing.